# Check the status of a file move by comparing directory sizes

Tags: javascript, php

i'm trying to use PHP to move some files, as it does that I have a script which will compare the source location with the destination location and work out the difference.

It all starts with a button like so:

```
<input type="button" class="upload_button" onClick="upload_images('drive_<?=$x["letter"]?>');start_upload_progress()" value="<?=$x["name"]?>"/>
```

This then starts these two scripts:

```
function upload_images(x) {
    var url = "http://localhost:1234/ppa/php/process_upload.php?x="+x
    doc("upload_iframe").src = url;
}
```

First of all it will change a hidden iframe url to the PHP script and send over the drive letter.

```
function start_upload_progress() {
    upload_progress("http://localhost:1234/ppa/php/upload_progress.php",function() {
        doc("upload_bar").innerHTML = this;
        if(this != 100) {
            //doc("upload_bar").innerHTML = x;
            setTimeout(start_upload_progress(),1000);
        }
    });
}
```

Next the above script will start, the console.log is simply for me to see if it's working, although I do not see "start" in my console. This function uses a callback, the below code simply loads a PHP script and returns the result. If the result is less than 100 then the call is made again every couple of seconds.

```
function upload_progress(url, callback) {
    var http = getHTTPObject();

    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            if (http.responseText == "true") {
                //window.location.replace("http://localhost:1234/ppa/rotate.php");
            }
            callback.call(http.responseText);
        }
    };
    http.open("GET", url, true);
    http.send();
}
```

Below is the PHP script, this was working when I set the $_SESSION['tmp'] variable manually.

```
<?php
session_start();
//If session has been created then ready to start progress bar
if (isset($_SESSION['tmp'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['tmp'] != "true") {
        $session_date = str_replace("/","",$_SESSION['session_date']);
        $tmp = explode("_", $_SESSION['tmp']);
        $upload_number = $tmp[1];
        $drive = $tmp[0];

        //get paths
        $destination = $_SESSION['ROOT_PATH']."data/images/".str_replace("/","",$_SESSION['session_date'])."/".$upload_number."/";
        $source = $drive.":/DCIM/";

        if (is_dir($destination) && is_dir($source)) {
            $source_size = foldersize($source);
            $destination_size = foldersize($destination);

            echo "Percentage: ".floor(($destination_size / $source_size * 100));
        }
    } else {
        echo "done: ".$_SESSION['tmp'];
    }
}

function foldersize($path) {
    $total_size = 0;
    $files = scandir($path);
    $cleanPath = rtrim($path, '/'). '/';

    foreach($files as $t) {
        if ($t<>"." && $t<>"..") {
            $currentFile = $cleanPath . $t;
            if (is_dir($currentFile)) {
                $size = foldersize($currentFile);
                $total_size += $size;
            }
            else {
                $size = filesize($currentFile);
                $total_size += $size;
            }
        }   
    }
    return $total_size;
}
?>
```

The $_SESSION['tmp'] variable is created just before the files begin to move, it seems like I can't access this session variable until the code has finish executing...

It is created here, at the top of the file moving script:

```
if (isset($drive)) {
    $x = explode("_", $drive);
    $x = $x[1];

    //Check if connected file exists
    if(file_exists($x.":/connected.txt")) {
        $file = file_get_contents($x.":/connected.txt");
        if ($file != false) {
            $file_code = split(":", $file);
            //Check if the file has the correct pass code
            if($file_code[0] == $code) {

                $_SESSION['tmp'] = $x."_".$drive;
```

When the files have finished moving the variable is set to "true", which seems to be the only value I can get...

Any ideas why my "start_upload_progress" function is not working? The console.log isn't running and I don't think the $_SESSION['tmp'] variable is setting until the file moving script has finished.

**Edit 2:**
I have got the script running, it compares the source and the destination and updated the innerHTML of the div with the difference. Only issue is that it only seems to work when I move the files from one place to the other manually.

The upload_progress script seems to freeze whilst the files are being moved, it should run at the same time to check the progress.

I have watched the files disappear from the source folder as well but all at the same time, shouldn't they move one by one as the scripting is only moving them one by one...

Comment: Any ideas about... what? You started the post with saying that you were trying to use PHP to move some files, and it looks like you were doing just fine. Is there a specific problem that you want us to help you solve?

Comment: What's `getHTTPObject()`? (always good to explain non-standard JS. Would have expected an `XMLHttpRequest` object here). Also, does your network tab show the URL getting fetched, and if so, what is the response your browser says it's getting?

Comment: That creates the http object for the ajax @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, see updated post

Comment: I guess that mostly leaves the question "which php file is moving the file, and is upload_progress.php a different file", because it'll have to be. What do you mean with "move it manually"? you `mv` the file from one dir to the other in a terminal?

Comment: There is a separate PHP file for each, so one for moving the file and another which compares the two locations. And when I say manually I mean by cutting and pasting the files in Windows Explorer